# CSS rules not applying to all fieldsets?

Tags: html, css, forms, fieldset

I have an issue where my style sheet isn't applying equally to all objects of the same type. Here is my HTML:

```
    <form method="post" action="FILLTHISINLATER" name="NewFeaturesRequest" target="_blank">
        <fieldset id="CustInfo">
            <legend>Customer Information</legend>
            <ol>
            <p>Please provide the name of the person requesting this new feature.</p>
            <li>
                <label id="lblFName" for="txtFName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="FName" tabindex="1" id="txtFName" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label id="lblLName" for="txtLName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="LName" tabindex="2" id="txtLName" />
            </li>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="FeatureInfo">
             <legend>New Feature Information</legend>
                <p align="left">What category does this feature fit into?</p>
                    <div id="radios" align="left">
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <input name="fType" type="radio" value="iPhone" />iPhone</li>
                            <li>
                                <input name="fType" type="radio" value="Messaging" />Messaging</li>
                            <li>
                                <input name="fType" type="radio" value="Contacts" />Contacts</li>
                         </ol>
                     </div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="AgentInfo">
              <legend>Support Agent</legend>
                  <p>Your Name: <select id="ddbxAGENT" name="ddbxAGENT" onchange="display_unlisted_agent()">
                        <option selected="selected">Select Your Name</option>
                        <option value="Allen">Allen</option>
                        <option value="Ash">Ash</option>
                        <option value="Beau">Beau</option>
                      </select>
                  </p>
         </fieldset>
```

I cut it down quite a bit. Next, my CSS for legend and fieldset (EDITED to include suggestion from misterManSam:

```
fieldset {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border-top: Green 2px solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom:none;
}
legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: Navy;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

And finally, what it actually looks like:

[image]

Why, oh why, is that green border on the second fieldset sticking out so far? The same style is used as on the other two, so what the heck is going on here? It happens in Chrome, IE, and Firefox. It's purely cosmetic, but having an error like that is unprofessional.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid in multiple spots. Run it through a validator to fix it.

Comment: If you have not already done so, try this at the top of your CSS: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` see if there is any change.

Comment: @j08691 - There were 2 errors in the code excerpt I posted here, one for Doctype not being in the code, and one for missing a quotation mark - which was irrelevant because it wasn't the cause of the problem, simple error on my part in transferring the code to stack overflow. Thank you, though. I edited my post to include the quotation.

Comment: @misterManSam - I added that into my style sheet, and it shortened the green border, but it still extends outside the form.

Comment: Time for a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net). Place everything in there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eqPQ7/2/

Comment: You have a `<p>` as a child of an `<ol>`, use deprecated attributes like align, and fail to close several tags.

Comment: @j08691 - You're right, sorry. I fixed all that right after posting this and forgot it was still in my original post. Thank you, though I'm not sure which tags I forgot to close. Everything is validating fine now after correcting the <p> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a width on `#infoboxes` you need to remove.

```
#infoboxes {
    /*width:650px;*/
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[Here is a Jsfiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/eqPQ7/3/)

Comment: Boom. Thanks so much. I should've looked more closely at the other things instead of focusing so much on the fieldset settings. I'm still a bit of a rookie, and probably bit off more than I can chew with this project, but thanks to you (and the other helpful posters!) I can move along.

Comment: no problem! remember that a block element, like `div` is by default, will take up the maximum amount of space of it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

The fieldset borders are expanding to the width of the container, whatever that may be.  You didn't show the code that's drawing the blue border around the whole form.  If I correct the HTML validation errors and put a width on the body tag, I get this, which appears to display correctly, *i.e.* all the fieldset top borders are the same width:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {width: 500px;}
fieldset {
  margin:0px;
  border-top: Green 2px solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom:none;
}
legend {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: Navy;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="FILLTHISINLATER" name="NewFeaturesRequest" target="_blank">
    <fieldset id="CustInfo">
        <legend>Customer Information</legend>
        <p>Please provide the name of the person requesting this new feature.</p>
        <ol>
        <li>
            <label id="lblFName" for="txtFName">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="FName" tabindex="1" id="txtFName" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label id="lblLName" for="txtLName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="LName" tabindex="2" id="txtLName" />
        </li></ol>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="FeatureInfo">
         <legend>New Feature Information</legend>
            <p align="left">What category does this feature fit into?</p>
                <div id="radios" align="left">
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <input name="fType" type="radio" value="iPhone" />iPhone</li>
                        <li>
                            <input name="fType" type="radio" value="Messaging" />Messaging</li>
                        <li>
                            <input name="fType" type="radio" value="Contacts" />Contacts</li>
                     </ol>
                 </div>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset id="AgentInfo">
          <legend>Support Agent</legend>
              <p>Your Name: <select id="ddbxAGENT" name="ddbxAGENT" onchange="display_unlisted_agent()">
                    <option selected="selected">Select Your Name</option>
                    <option value="Allen">Allen</option>
                    <option value="Ash">Ash</option>
                    <option value="Beau">Beau</option>
                  </select>
              </p>
     </fieldset>
```

I note some `align="left"` attributes which should be replaced with CSS, but they do not appear to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I saw it, I went and scrutinized my <div> tags, but it turned out to be an issue with my ID on the tags within the field.